# Sharepoint 2013 has two different calendar app icons?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have noticed that the icons for some of the Calendar apps added into our Sharepoint 2013 Enterprise intranet site (when viewed under "Site Contents") show up as a large white calendar grid on a blue tile but others are shown as a smaller gold-coloured calendar on the same type of blue tile. Can anyone tell me what the differences mean? I can't find any references to this in the documentation.
Thanks, John

Comment: I am sure if you would have provided a screenshot you would have got an answer much faster :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have SharePoint 2013 in use. All SharePoint 2013 apps are using the blue and white icons. All **SharePoint 2010** apps are using the colored (gold style) icons.

See the following screenshots (all from SharePoint 2013 site contents)

This is a site after migration from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013. You will see the gold styled icons as the apps are SharePoint 2010 apps.

[image]

This is a screenshot of site contents in SharePoint 2013 just containing SharePoint 2013 native apps. You will see all of them being blue and white.

[image]

But it is possible to add SharePoint 2010 apps e.g. from a template to a SharePoint 2013 native site. Then you will see single gold style apps within SharePoint 2013 apps.

[image]

I hope this could answer your question "Can anyone tell me what the differences mean?".

**If this answer helps please mark as answer. Thank you.**